# String unreadable when passing from one form to another in C#

Tags: c#, string, winforms

I am trying to pass a string from Form2.cs to Form1.cs and then display it in a message box. For some reason, the variable in the string is not showing but the rest of the text is.

Form1.cs

```
 Form2 otherForm = new Form2();

public void getOtherTextBox()
        {
            otherForm.TextBox1.Text = player1;
    }

    private void labelClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label clickedLabel = (Label)sender;

        if (clickedLabel.BackColor != Color.Transparent)
        {
            return;
        }

        clickedLabel.BackColor = isBlackTurn ? Color.Black : Color.White;
        isBlackTurn = !isBlackTurn;

        Color? winner = WinCheck.CheckWinner(board);
        if (winner == Color.Black)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(  player1 + " is the winner!");
        }
        else if (winner == Color.White)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("White is the winner!");
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
```

Form2.cs

```
public TextBox TextBox1
    {
        get
        {
            return textBox1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you make sure the other form is instantiated? and u ddint use your getOtherTextBox() function in the button event .. that maybe the bug.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way round i.e. `player1=otherForm.TextBox1.Text;`

Comment: Doesn't change anything. What would the click function be though? To memorize or store the string?

Comment: Why dont you pass the value of textbox from Form2 to Form1 when you creates Form1 and Show it up?

Comment: By the way, you don't need to make a public property for your control. You can make it public itself using designer.

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro How do I do that?

Comment: @user3777772 I will answer

Answer (score 0):

this might work .. u need to call the function somewhere to make it work.

I fixed it by calling it in the label click;
so u need to click the label to update the value in the other form.

u can add this function to events like a timer event which ensures that it's always updated within a perfect time.

```
public void getOtherTextBox()
{
    otherForm.TextBox1.Text = player1;
}

private void labelClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label clickedLabel = (Label)sender;
    getOtherTextBox();

    if (clickedLabel.BackColor != Color.Transparent)
    {
        return;
    }

    clickedLabel.BackColor = isBlackTurn ? Color.Black : Color.White;
    isBlackTurn = !isBlackTurn;

    Color? winner = WinCheck.CheckWinner(board);
    if (winner == Color.Black)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(  player1 + " is the winner!");
    }
    else if (winner == Color.White)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("White is the winner!");
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can create a property in Form1 to hold the player name, and then in Form2, when the input of player name changed, you will update the property of Form1. See the code:

```
public class Form1()
{
    //Code
    private string PlayerName { get; set; }

    private void labelClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label clickedLabel = (Label)sender;

        if (clickedLabel.BackColor != Color.Transparent)
            return;

        clickedLabel.BackColor = isBlackTurn ? Color.Black : Color.White;
        isBlackTurn = !isBlackTurn;

        Color? winner = WinCheck.CheckWinner(board);
        if (winner == Color.Black)
            MessageBox.Show(this._playerName + " is the winner!");
        else if (winner == Color.White)
            MessageBox.Show("White is the winner!");
    }

    //More code
}


public class Form2()
{
    private Form1 _frm;

    public Form2()
    {
        this._frm = new Form1();
    }
    public void ShowFormWinner()
    {
        _frm.PlayerName = textBox1.Text;
        _frm.Show();
    }

    public void OnPlayerNameChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _frm.PlayerName = textBox1.Text;
        _frm.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok this works but only on the initial text in the textbox. After a user types something in, that doesn't show only.

Comment: @user3777772 I changed my code to fit the new scenario.

Comment: No this doesn't work, the project won't even load with this code.